# Non-HTTP-Chunked Multipart POST with apache httpclient

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is there a way to send multipart POST requests via the Apache HTTPClient library that does not use Chunked HTTP Encoding?

I'm trying to upload files to Wikimedia Commons, and they are still using HTTP/1.0 - so I'm unable to actually upload anything.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to configure HttpClient to use HTTP/1.0. This will automatically disable chunk coded transfer encoding for entity closing requests.

Comment: I tried with httpcomponents-client-4.2.3 but got
`Exception: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Chunked transfer encoding not allowed for HTTP/1.0`
The only workaround in these older version seems to be local file access
instead of using an input stream.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version. HTTP/1.0 supports Content-Length delineated messages only. If the length is not known http agent is unable to generate a well formed request message